# Why afBedSheet don't see my types?

Tags: fantom, afbedsheet

I'm running a [BedSheet](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afBedSheet/) application but when I make a HTTP request to a particular route, I get this error in the browser

```
500 - Internal Server Error
afBeanUtils::TypeNotFoundErr
- Could not find match for Type mypod::MyClass. 

Available Values

afBedSheet::FileAsset
afBedSheet::HttpStatus
afBedSheet::MethodCall
afBedSheet::Redirect
afBedSheet::Text
sys::File
sys::InStream

afBeanUtils::TypeNotFoundErr : Could not find match for Type mypod::MyClass.
  afBeanUtils::TypeLookup.check (TypeLookup.fan:157)
    afBeanUtils::TypeLookup.doFindParent (TypeLookup.fan:140)
```

However MyClass is there and it is being instantiated by other class. Why is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Err msg could be a little more informative...

It sounds like your request handler is returning an instance of `mypod::MyClass` and BedSheet is complaining that it doesn't know what to do with it.

You probably want to be returning an instance of `afBedSheet::Text` as in:

```java
Obj indexPage() {
  return Text.fromHtml("<html>Hello!</html>")
}
```

If the above doesn't sound right, then I'd need to see some code to be of further help.

Comment: Awesome! that was the problem. I was returning the object, not its Text (JSON) form. I agree that the Err message could be more informative.

Comment: New Err Msg - https://bitbucket.org/AlienFactory/afbedsheet/commits/6174914f457b8d2aae7737e3e144463dd1672860